# Finding whether an element available in GenericList

Tags: c#, generic-list

I have a string[] which contains value {"data1","data2","data3"}.

and i have a GenericList which contains

data2

data4

two records

i want to get the common datas which is avail in string[] and the genericList

Comment: What exactly is the type of the list, and of its contents?

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried something like

```
string[] s = {"data1", "data2", "data3"};
List<string> list = new List<string> { "data2", "data3" };
var commonList = list.Intersect(s);
```

Have a look at [Enumerable.Intersect Method (IEnumerable, IEnumerable)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460136.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming it's a `List<string>` and you're using .NET 3.5 or higher, you can use the [`Intersect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.intersect.aspx) method from LINQ to Objects:

```
var intersection = stringArray.Intersect(stringList);
```

Note that this will return a lazily-evaluated `IEnumerable<string>`. If you need it in an array or a list, call the relevant method:

```
var intersectionArray = stringArray.Intersect(stringList).ToArray();
// or
var intersectionList = stringArray.Intersect(stringList).ToList();
```

Also note that this is a *set* operation - so the result will not contain any duplicates, even if there is duplication of a particular element in both the original collections.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the `Intersect` extension method [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460136.aspx)

```
  string[] c1 = { "data1", "data2", "data3" };
  string[] c2 = { "data2", "data4" };

  IEnumerable<string> both = c1.Intersect(c2);

  foreach (string s in both) Console.WriteLine(s);
```

Will print *data2*.